# MongoDb query too slow

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

I am executing a query, to get data from the database, it takes more than 6 seconds, the same query when I execute it in studio 3T, it executes really fast.
I also executed explain()

```
executionStats: {
      executionSuccess: true,
      nReturned: 932,
      executionTimeMillis: 4,
      totalKeysExamined: 0,
      totalDocsExamined: 5149,
      executionStages: [Object],
      allPlansExecution: []
}
```

as you see the execution time is fast, but the result take 6 seconds to return.
I am printing the time to see how it takes

```
console.log("Before", Date())
const posts = await Post.find({ author: author._id })
console.log("After", Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first query you are making, so that it actually has to connect to the server? The connection process takes some time (although 6 seconds seems excessive).

Try:

```
const posts = await Post.find({ author: author._id })
console.log("Before", Date())
const posts = await Post.find({ author: author._id })
console.log("After", Date())
```

This ensures you are benchmarking the find and not whatever setup may be happening behind the scenes.